# Should I call SPWeb.Update after changing the value of ParserEnabled

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

If I have the following code:

```
var web = SPContext.Current.Web;
web.ParserEnabled = false;
// !!! is web.Update() required here?
// ...
// add a document or otherwise change things
// ...
web.ParserEnabled = true;
```

Do I have to explicitly call the Update method to commit the change to the ParserEnabled property or is it checked at runtime by the methods that care about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to call `.Update()` when you change other properties that aren't persisted to the database (`.AllowUnsafeUpdates` for example), so I don't think you'll need to do that here.

If you encounter issues, you can always try adding the call to your code.

Comment: I ran some tests this morning and changing the value of ParserEnabled was not persisted between requests (or really instantiations of SPSite/SPWeb) unless I called .Update() after setting it. If I called the Update method it would stick as expected.